# Remove /index.php/ from Zeus rewrite.script WordPress permalinks

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, zeus

I have set up a WordPress site for a client of mine on my own server.  When I was ready to transfer it over to his server I noticed that his host uses Zeus instead of Apache.  I have never used Zeus before.

The only problem is that Zeus doesn't use mod_rewrite so permalinks didn't work.  I searched around online to find a rewrite.script that works for Zeus, found one, but the problem is it acts like the fake apache mod_rewrite by adding /index.php/ to the URL path.

Does anyone know how to get rid of it so my URL's change from:

mydomain.com/index.php/friendly-url

to

mydomain.com/friendly-url?

Here is my rewrite.script file

```
#Zeus webserver version of basic WordPress mod_rewrite rules
map path into SCRATCH:path from %{URL}
look for file at %{SCRATCH:path}
if exists then goto END
look for dir at %{SCRATCH:path}
if exists then goto END
##### FIX FOR LOGIN/FORGOTTEN PASSWORD/ADMIN ETC #####
match URL into $ with ^/wp-.*$
if matched then goto END
##### FIX TO ALLOW SEARCH TO WORK #####
match URL into $ with ^/(.*)
set URL = /$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this, which appears to be exactly what you're looking for: http://www.adamchristie.co.uk/wordpress/seo-friendly-wordpress-urls-on-namesco-zeus-servers/

Hope that helps!